# Creating an index file for an xml file

Tags: xml, indexing

I am not exactly sure how to create an index file for an XML file. My XML file contains mostly football player names, so I want to index those names. Now I thought about creating a dictionary where one key (player name) would have multiple values which would be line numbers where they are recorded in the XML file. Then if there was a query to find a player by name I could use the index to get line numbers where the player is in the text file and fetch only those lines from the XML file. Now, this is where I am not so sure if it can work because as I found I would still have to iterate over the whole input XML file to get to the line number I want. I just want some input if what I'm thinking is wrong or if the use of index should be different, or even if I can fetch only a certain line from an XML file by line number.

Comment: XML is not designed for random access. Use a database instead.

Comment: XML files don't work by *line number*. White space in an XML file is irrelevant outside of a CDATA section.Your requirements won't work, anyway. What happens if a new player is added in the middle of the XML file? All of your index values become invalid. Don't try to use XML for this purpose; use a more proper storage system  like a database. You need to add more than one tool to your toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

You do realize that XML files are B-Trees, not tables, right? They are also multidimensional, and each branch has its own number of dimensions. Such a schema isn't easy to index in the way one indexes a database.

The problem is usually solved by pre-solving the responses to the most commonly used queries, same as caching on the code level. In other words, cache your responses, because you won't find what you're looking for.

PS There's a commercial database that "indexes" XML, but it does exactly that: caches (or pre-calculates) the queries.